# Where are django-lean reports stored?

Tags: django

I'm new to django-lean.

Does anyone know where are the reports generated by calling manage.py update_experiment_reports  are stored?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have django-lean installed, but based on [experiments.reports](http://bitbucket.org/akoha/django-lean/src/tip/experiments/reports.py), I would suggest looking at these two tables (even via the admin), DailyConversionReport and DailyEngagementReport.

Answer (score 0):

You can access these reports via:

`/admin/django-lean/<experiment_name>/`